# Regarding a conclusion of a step involving solvable factorgroups and solvable normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, solution-verification, normal-subgroups

I have the following given equation where I don't understand the conclusion:

Given
$$ G^{(n)}N/N = (G/N)^{(n)} = \{N\}$$
Why does it follow, that $G^{(n)} \subseteq N$?

$G^{(n)}$ is the n-th commutator subgroup, $N$ is a soluble normal subgroup and $(G/N)^{(n)}$ is also soluble.

My thoughts/explanation about this is: $$\text{ If we have } G^{(n)}N/N = \{N\}, \text{ then } G^{(n)} \subseteq N, \text{ otherwise there exists } {\sigma \in G^{(n)}\setminus N} \text{ such that } {\sigma N \neq N}, \text{ in contradiction to } G^{(n)}N/N = \{N\}, \text{ since } \sigma N \in  G^{(n)}N/N$$

Comment: I guess to the trained eye this conclusion seems obvious, but to me (an instance of the untrained), algebra has so many (may I say) convoluted terms, that it is hard to keep track of, hence the confusion.